# What is the status of drug decriminalization in Indonesia?

Tags: drugs, war-on-drugs

https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https://bnn.go.id/ipwl-dekriminalisasi-ala-indonesia/

This says

> Regarding the optimization of IPWL, the Head of BNN said that in
> principle the institution reflects Indonesian-style decriminalization.
> If an addict reports to IPWL, then he will not undergo a legal process
> like a criminal. However, currently the decriminalization of drug
> users has not been carried out as expected. The indication is that
> many addicts or drug abusers are actually punished and not
> rehabilitated,

So, what is the status here? Are drugs decriminalized? If so, what laws, or decisions make  it official?

If Indonesia does decriminalize drugs, then why is the decriminalization, "fail"?

Comment: Hello, please check out the [tour] and the [help] as well as the [ask], but welcome to politics SE.

Comment: How can I improve my questions. Many of my friends are drug users and they told me that if we really have decriminalization they want to take advantage of it. However, most people still go to jail and this country is so corrupt I am not sure it's just a matter of law. Basically I have no idea if we even have real decriminalization. The narative seems to be around that governments try to help addicted people even though most drug users are not addicted at all

Comment: With your analogy, you have to consider that Bob might actually LIKE punching people.

Comment: I think this is a valid question, but you should really pick **one** question and state it as the main.  Something like **What is the status of drug decriminalization in Indonesia?**  The rest can be put in a supporting/contextual questions, maybe if clearly indicated so (some people are really picky about multiple sub-questions).  Point out that 80% of jail pop is for drug offenses.  Things that are missing though:  what drugs are de-crimininalized in Indonesia, what drugs are those 80%-people in jail for and were they incarcerated after or before decrim?  I'll vote to reopen if edited.

Comment: Oh, and lose Bob analogy.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica you know you can just edit the post yourself, right?

Comment: @EkadhSingh I do.  I also dislike when people change the meaning of my posts...

Comment: I edit the question. I wonder what else I should edit..  There are so many contexts that I do not know for sure.

Comment: How about making it much shorter, without so much of your opinions and comments?  *"What is the status of drug decriminalization in Indonesia?  One government agency, says that it isn't working because judges keep sending people to jail instead of rehabilitating users."*   Add your quote of the BNN head.  The rest doesn't really need to be there.  I don't want to tell you what to write, but people did have valid reasons to close, as per the rules of this site.  I didn't vote to close and in fact I upvoted it, but it will get shut down again if you leave it as is.

Comment: Done. The issue is most people here don't understand the issue in Indonesia. Basically I like to give lots of background check but I want political experts to tell me what's really going on. It's like a client asking a lawyer you know. I know the fact more than most but the lawyers know the laws far more than I am

Comment: @obfuscated on SE.History, I recently asked a vaccine question.  As vaccines are a touchy subject, I tried to add some comments "making my position clear".  Question got closed and pretty heavily downvoted :-( Stripped down to just my original question, it was reopened, somewhat upvoted and I got an answer.  Sometimes it's better just not to put too much of your opinion and "background info" into a question ;-)

Comment: Okay. There you go